# "How to scrape data from multiple pages of links while maintaining the dynamic webpage state of the previous link upon returning?"

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

"I want to scrape all the data fields from https://coop.moi.gov.tw/cphp/co100View/list, which has over 7,000 records, with 10 records per page. I want to scrape the detailed information provided within each hyperlink on each page. However, when I use Selenium to click on the hyperlink and return to the previous page, my filtering conditions disappear and the page jumps back to the first page, making it difficult for me to quickly scrape all the data within each link.

Below is the code I have tried to extract the title outside of the links, but I haven't tried it yet because I discovered the issue before attempting:"

```
import time
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import openpyxl
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


# 创建浏览器对象，这里使用Chrome浏览器
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# 发出GET请求
url = "https://coop.moi.gov.tw/cphp/co100View/list"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
#選擇農業類
ElementFindOption = driver.find_element("id","qtype1")
all_options = ElementFindOption.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"option")
all_options[1].click()

#選擇已登記
ElementFindOption2 = driver.find_element("id","qstatus")
all_options2 = ElementFindOption2.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"option")
all_options2[1].click()

#點選查詢
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="coopForm"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/button[1]').click()
time.sleep(1)

# 创建Excel文件
workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.active
sheet.title = "Table Data"
# 等待 table 出现，最多等待 10 秒
start_time = time.time()
while True:
    if time.time() - start_time > 10:
        raise Exception("Time out! Can't find table.")
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        table = soup.find('div', {'class': 'table-responsive'}).find('table')

        if table is not None:
            break
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"出现了错误：{e}")
        pass
    time.sleep(0.5)

# 将表格数据写入Excel文件
rows = table.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    row_data = []
    for cell in row.find_all(['td', 'th']):
        row_data.append(cell.text.strip())
    sheet.append(row_data)

# 点击“下一页”按钮
while True:
    try:
        print("執行寫入資料")
        next_button_locator = (By.LINK_TEXT, "下一頁")
        next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(next_button_locator))
        time.sleep(0.1)
        next_button.click()

        # 等待 table 出现，最多等待 10 秒
        start_time = time.time()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        while True:
            if time.time() - start_time > 10:
                raise Exception("Time out! Can't find table.")
            try:
                time.sleep(0.1)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
                table = soup.find('div', {'class': 'table-responsive'}).find('table')

                if table is not None:
                    break
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"出现了错误：{e}")
                pass
            time.sleep(1)

        # 将下一页的表格数据写入Excel文件
        rows = table.find_all('tr')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        for row in rows:
            row_data = []
            for cell in row.find_all(['td', 'th']):
                time.sleep(0.1)
                row_data.append(cell.text.strip())
            sheet.append(row_data)

        # 顯示完成提示
        print(f"第{sheet.max_row // 10 + 1}頁資料已經正確完成。")

    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("已經到最後一頁或找不到下一頁按鈕")
        break
    except Exception as e:
      
        print("出現了意外的錯誤")
        break

# 保存Excel文件
workbook.save("table_data.xlsx")

# 取得目前工作目錄路徑
path = os.getcwd()

# 关闭浏览器
driver.quit()

# 顯示
print("程式執行完成！")
```

I hope someone can solve my problem or propose other solutions.